# How can I get a field?

Tags: umbraco

I'm trying to create a partial view macro that list all items (blog entries). I can read its name, but not the entry field like it's content:

```
@foreach (var page in CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible").OrderBy("CreateDate desc"))
{   
    <div class="article">
        <div class="articletitle">@page.Name</div>
        <div class="articlepreview">
            @Umbraco.Truncate(@page.Field("pageContent"),100)           
            <a href="@page.Url">Read More..</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr/>
}
```

All pages are defined as a `ContentPage` (document type) where I've added `Page Content (pageContent), type: Richtext editor` as a `Tab: Content` element.

Do I need to cast the page or something to `Contentpage`?

What Im trying to do Is to give a 100 char long preview of the content on my main page so the users can read a short excerpt before clicking on the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically they are Properties of a doctype, not Fields.

So I believe this is what you are looking for:

> @page.GetProperty("pageContent").Value

And truncate...

> @Library.Truncate(@page.GetProperty("pageContent").Value,100)

**However** in this context you should be able to simply use…

> @page.pageContent

So...

> @Library.Truncate(@page.pageContent,100)

…should work!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you the text you are looking for (I think your problem was just that extra @):

```
@Umbraco.Truncate(page.Field("pageContent"),100)
```

If you are running on umbraco 7+, try this:

```
@Umbraco.Truncate(page.AsDynamic().pageContent, 100)
```

Hope this helps!